# try to change bin log directory: mysql-bin.index not found (Errcode: 13)

Tags: mysql, logging, bin

MySQL 5.1.54
Ubuntu 11.04

I'am try to change bin log directory in my.conf as:

```
[mysqld]
log_bin=/home/developer/logs/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

After this changes MySQL server can't start with error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/home/developer/logs/mysql/mysql-bin.index' 
not found (Errcode: 13)
111005 12:47:58 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Permission for directory /home/developer/logs/mysql/ is 0777

What's going on?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As usual, the solution was simple but not obvious: it needed to edit apparmor settings
I just added to **/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld** a new string with path to target directory: **/home/developer/logs/* rw**

It works!

Comment: apparmor.d is not available in my server.

Comment: Note, for anyone getting to this. If you want the apparmor path to include all subfolders in the path as well, use two stars \*\*, for example(without quotes): "**/home/developer/logs/\*\* rw,**"

Comment: also don't forget a `service apparmor restart` afterwards

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 MySQL 8 should append "/home/developer/logs/** rwk,"，grant permission to lock a file.

Answer (score 27):

> /usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/usr/binlogs/mysql-bin.index' not found
>   (Errcode: 13)

It worked for me with:

> chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/binlogs/

Comment: This is the most obvious solution after an accidental deletion of the mysql bin logs. Perfect !

Comment: @Maxx what would be its windows equivalent

Answer (score 15):

Just as an FYI for anyone who runs into a similar problem, the solution is basically the same, but the cause of the problem isn't obvious.

After upgrading Debian wheezy, mysql failed to start.

Somehow, I have no idea how, permissions on some of the files in `/var/lib/mysql` were not owned by the mysql user, thus preventing the server from firing up.

A `chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql` fixed it.

I didn't do anything to mess up mysql, it was a standard:

```
apt-get update

apt-get upgrade
```

Something got hinky during the Debian upgrade and manual intervention was needed.

Comment: Thank you @Halfstop, you saved my day. works perfect

Answer (score 3):

Selinux might enforce the rule that MySQL database files have to live in /var/lib/mysql and not anywhere else. Try turning off selinux (selinux=0 on kernel boot command line) if you moved mysql to another directory.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1:

1. `service mysqld stop`
2. Copy the log files including the .index file to new location.

   ```
    cp mysql-bin.log* /path/to/binlogs
    cp mysql-bin.index /path/to/binlogs
   ```
3. Do Changes in the `/etc/my.cnf` file.

   ```
   [mysqld]
   log-bin=/path/to/newdirecory/mysql-bin

   log-bin-index=/path/to/newdirectory/mysql-bin.index
   ```
4. `service mysqld start`

Option 2:

Use this utiltiy to relocate binary logs:

```
mysqlbinlogmove --binlog-dir=/server/data /new/binlog_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give user permissions to the directory as follows:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /home/developer/logs/mysql/
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your user have access to all upper directories? In special, the /home/developer/ directory? Try to log in with the mysql server account and touch the log file.

Comment: i have copied permissions from /var/log/mysql directory. No results.

Comment: and what happens if you su to the mysqld user and try to access the directory?

Comment: i run "sudo -u mysql touch /home/developer/logs/test.txt", it succesfully created a file

Comment: I believe in this case the error message and the error code are misleading ... When I hit this, I've even tried to create a new index file with the list of binary logs ..., this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

> mysqld: File '/data/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 2
>   - No such file or directory)

I was really stuck in the middle of my MySQL Master - Slave setup. Finally the above was a permission issue, adding the below command solved my issue.

> chown -R mysql:mysql /data/log/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to change the *datadir* variable during a fresh install. The solution in my case was to run the first time start up with log-bin disabled. After that I was able to enable it again using the new path ...

Comment: What do you mean?

stop server -> disable log_bin ->start server ->...stop server->enable log_bin -> start server_ ???  unfortunately it's not worked for me

Comment: Not exactly. Do you also change the datadir position? If yes, this is what I did in order to make it work: disable log-bin in the configuration file, mysql_install_db with the customized configuration file, at the end of the installation mysqld is started by the install script. After that: stop, enable log-bin, start.

Comment: It should be noted that this was during a new setup. If you have an existing database, your situation is different.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is wrong:

```
log_bin=/home/developer/logs/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

You would use instead

```
log-bin=/home/developer/logs/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

Answer (score 0):

During replication configuration in "my.cnf" file needs to mention

server-id=1
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log

you can make your own directory and give permission.
create directory "mysql" in /var/log/

> chmod 777 mysql

this is applicable with MySQL version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You can also comment the line in `my.cnf` file which is defining the log location, so mysql will consider its default path and will start properly.

`log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log` -> `#log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log`.

This will be helpful if you are not concerned much about logs.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation in mysql say https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin

The variable is log_bin and not log-bin at least in version 5.7

Comment: the original question shows the user is using MySQL version 5.1.54, so this would not apply